# MX Record not working

Tags: sendmail, mx-record

I'm almost done configuring my nameservers for my domain. Everything works fine website responding...but My MX record don't seem to be working, and I tried a lot of things. I created a cname with subdomain pop and smtp an MX record with webhost4life.com has a host name (but I have no idea if it should be that host) i did try mail.webhost4life.com but nothing seem to be working. If you compare intoDNS.com datahex.ca and myhaccpplan.com (which the MX is working) maybe you could help me figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

I'm configuring my nameserver on zoneedit.com.

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that mail server MX record is referring has A record, CNAME is not enough. This is important but I do no remember why. Here is an example:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
@       IN SOA  dns0.yourisp.com. zone.yourisp.com. 1308717736 21600 7200 1209600 10800
@       IN NS   dns1.yourisp.com.
@       IN NS   dns2.yourisp.com.
@       IN MX   10 mail.example.com.
mail    IN A    192.168.1.200
...
```

Also, make sure there is corresponding PTR record that resolves IP addres to the name of your mail server. This is not directly related to your problem, but it is important for successful mail delivery.

```
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
@       IN  SOA     dns0.yourisp.com. zone.yourisp.com. 2011041900 3h 15m 3w 3h
@       IN  NS      dns1.yourisp.com.
@       IN  NS      dns2.yourisp.com.
200     IN  PTR     mail.example.com.
...
```

Once you have your mail working consider adding [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) record.

Comment: CNAMEs will work for MX Record entries, they are just not RFC compliant.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, here is my setup.. I can receive emails on datahex.ca but i can't send email from datahex.ca :

@ IN MX 7200 10 mail.datahex.ca
mail IN A 7200 (66.96.142.50) 
50 IN PTR 7200 mail.datahex.ca
@       IN  NS      ns8.zoneedit.com.
@       IN  NS      ns4.zoneedit.com

Comment: is the IP suppose to be my Public IP ? in this case I put the address that is working for other domain...

Comment: `CNAME`s do _not_ work if used for domains in `MX` records, contrary to the false claim above.  The loop prevention algorithm specified by the SMTP standard _breaks_ if the SMTP Relay client system is a fallback mail exchanger but the name used for it in `MX` records is an alias via a `CNAME` resource record.